# Number of shards in dynamodb

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

how can I know how many shards a dynamo Db stream have? Lambda function can have only 100 concurrent function running per account so my concern is that if number of hards are greater than 100 than how Lambda manages processing of shards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Lambda function limit refers to 100 *unique* functions running per account, not number of times the same function is executed/executing on your stream. Therefore, your stream can have any number of shards and if you only have one Lambda function running it will handle processing of all shards.

To answer your original answer, a [DescribeStream](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/dynamodbstreams/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeStream.html) API call to your stream will return all the shards under the stream, so you can obtain the number from there if you are still curious.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a limit on concurrent execution of Lambda functions. By default it's 100 and if you have more than 100 shards which tries to execute more than 100 lambda executions concurrently it will hit the limits.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html?shortFooter=true#limits_lambda